# How to break while loop after condition meet in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, loops, while-loop

I am printing `$row->title` when **while loop meet some condition**, but unfortunately without breaking it is printing all the results. Below is an example where 1st `[_id]` matching with last `[_id]` so it has to print only first value `['title']` which is MarQ, but it is printing both Marq and Jean.

My DB is like this  -

```
    MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                (
                    [oid] => 5fcbd8fbecf357fae06e2264
                )
    [title] = MarQ,
    [age] = 22
)
)

MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                (
                    [oid] => 9s8393hf83959348200d
                )
    [title] = Bennet,
    [age] = 29
)
)

MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID Object
                (
                    [oid] => 5fcbd8fbecf357fae06e2264
                )
    [title] = Jean,
    [age] = 20
)
)
```

Here I am trying to Matching `id` if id matches it will print only first value in while loop.

but in my code it is printing all the values rather than only first value.

```
    foreach ($cursor as $row) {

         $i = 0;

      while ($i < count($row)) {

       $id   = isset($row[$i]["_id"]);

        $j = $i + 1;
while ($j < count($row) && $id == isset($row[$j]["_id"])) {
         $r++;
                   ?>
          <?php
         echo '<br>';
    ?>
     <?php

    $j++;
}
      $i++;
                    }
              }
```

(I have to do this only in while loop).

Comment: @FSford after putting `break;` still it printing is there any other way to to it without while loop too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` to break out of a loop.
[Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

```
 foreach ($cursor as $row) {

         $i = 0;

      while ($i < count($row)) {

       $id   = isset($row[$i]["_id"]);

        $j = $i + 1;
while ($j < count($row) && $id == isset($row[$j]["_id"])) {
         $r++;
         break;
                   ?>
          <?php
         echo '<br>';
    ?>
     <?php

    $j++;
}
      $i++;
                    }
              }
```

Comment: after putting `break;` still it printing is there any other way to to it without while loop too?